# using a project as a library, but needing to change the contentView

Tags: java, android

I have a android project as a library, and this library contains a home screen. The new app needs this home screen (as well as everything else in the library), but but also needs to make changes to all of the graphics, as well as add a few new buttons, how would I do this?

I don't want to edit the library. I can make the new app have images with the same name as the library, so the new images over-take the libraries images. But this doesn't help me in adding in 3 new buttons to the layout, as well as the new pieces of functionality to the activity (while keeping all of the old functionality).

Any one have any experience with this sort of thing?

Comment: So, will your main activity extend the `home screen` activity from the library?

Comment: Currently there are no activities at all in the new app. It is using everything from the old app. Should I make a activity in the project, and extend the libraries activity? Will this then allow me to change the layout, add functionality, while keeping all of the old functionality?

Comment: Yes, by extending your library's activity, and overriding onCreate(Bundle), you can keep the prior functionality intact, and add new widgets. Make sure your new activity's `onCreate(Bundle)` also handles the widgets that were in old activity's layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `home screen` activity from the library. Override the `onCreate(Bundle)`:

```
public class NewMainActivity extends HomeScreenActivityFromLibrary {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View viewFromLibrary = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                                      library.package.name.R.layout.home_screen, null);

        // Make changes; add Buttons to `viewFromLibrary`
        // Add functionality to Buttons; setOnClickListeners

        setContentView(viewFromLibrary);
    }
}
```

Depending upon how your `HomeScreenActivityFromLibrary` is setup, you may have to override additional methods. Another thing you can do is: simply copy the layout file used in `HomeScreenActivityFromLibrary` to your project's `res/layout` folder. Add additional widgets(buttons etc.) in the xml file. In this case, all you need to do is:

```
public class NewMainActivity extends HomeScreenActivityFromLibrary {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.newly_created_xml_file);

        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_id);
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```